# Is there any way to remove pagination ID from URL?

Tags: magento2, url, pagination

I'm wondering Like, Is there any way to remove Pagination Page ID from URL?

Like, I moved to the second page or any other page during listing page.

SO URL will be changed as default behavior of **Magento** as

https://www.example.com/cat-url.html?p=2

How to remove **p=2**?

Every Suggestions appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I'm using custom module to load products on category page via Ajax.

https://amasty.com/infinite-scroll-for-magento-2.html

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You may try to rewrite the url like in this post: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/221213

Answer (score 1):

I would say it would be pain in the ... But one idea came to my mind is it could be done by using ajax. When customer click the link to navigate the next page. Save the number of page in somewhere for example local storage, after that we can fetch data via ajax. Then if we get the correct response, inject that to product list, remove that page in URl, finally updates page number in local storage. I think by doing that you can have the nice url as you wish. But there is quite a lot of work to archive that.